# get local pharmacies geolocation info

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-places-api

I want to add a map to my application to locate pharmacies in my country and add a markers in the map with my current location.

Should I do this manually by adding the latitude and longitude of each pharmacy?

First this method is a little tiring because there is a lot of pharmacies. Secondly it's not effective because I must be aware of any opening of a new pharmacy.

Can you help me because I feel lost.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.example.dell.medicalrepresentative.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                    .title("Marker"));
        }
    }
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I added these permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission
    android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```